# how to check if the password matches before changing to new one passport

Tags: javascript, mongoose, passport.js

I'm building an application and I'm struggling with the password update with passport and MongoDB.
I want to check if the user has entered his actual password and it matches what is stored in the DB before setting a new one.

This is what I've got so far:

```js
if (req.body.password == req.user.password) {
  if (req.body.newPassword.normalize() == req.body.confirmPassword.normalize()) {
    // Verifying if the new password matches the confirmation one
    // before actually changing the password (This part works)
  }
} else {
  // Handling if the old password does not match the DB
}
res.redirect('/profile')
```

I 've been trying thing like:

```js
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({
      username: req.user.email
    }, function(err, user) {
      if (err) {
        return done(err);
      }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false);
      }
      if (!user.verifyPassword(req.body.password)) {
        return done(null, false);
      }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
```

Still, not working... Any hints? :)

**EDIT**

I've been using crypto in atempt to get the same hash that the one stored in MongoDB. To register a new user, I use passport.

```
let hash = crypto.createHmac('sha256', secret)
               .update('I love cupcakes') // I have no idea of what this this line does, actually...
               .digest('hex');
console.log(hash);
```

I guess that at some point I should pass the DB-stored salt to a fonction to verify the the password he submited is the same that the one stored, I just have no clue how to do it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a lot internet search, I came up with this:

```
async function fooChangePW(req,res){
req.user.changePassword(req.body.password, req.body.newPassword)
.then(() => {
    console.log('password changed');
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
})
  res.redirect('/profile')
}
```

Since the user is already authenticated, whe can go with `req.user.changePassword(oldPassword, newPassword)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to hash the received `req.body.password` using the secret and see if it matches the already hashed password saved in the DB.
If it does, it's the same old password.

Comment: I've been experimenting with something similar, but I did not achieve to get the same hash from passportjs while using crypto. Do you know how to do it ? I'll update my question with what I've done